# ODE Interval of Validity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The problem is stated as such;

> Solve the I.V.P
>   $$y'=\frac{1+3x^2}{3y^2-6y}; y(0)=1
> $$and determine the interval in which the solution is valid.

The hint given is:  To find the interval of definition, look for points where the integral curve has a vertical tangent line.

I was able to solve the IVP with the following solution;

$$y^3-3y^2-x-x^3+2=0$$

But with the hint, I am under the assumption that the curve has vertical tangent lines when the denominator of the derivative is equal to 0, which would be when $y=0$ and $y=2$.  But the solution is give as $|x|<1$.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should've gotten $y(x)^3 - 3y(x)^2 +2 - x - x^3 = 0$

Comment: You are right...  I'll fix.

Comment: Then plug in $y=0,2$ to this correct equation, and note that you obtain $x=\pm 1$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense... but why $|x|<1$ as opposed to $|x|>1$?

Comment: Because it starts at $y(0)=1$ and is continuous. If you prescribed an initial condition at maybe $x=5$, then perhaps we should restrict to  $x>1$

Comment: Ah, that also makes sense.  Because the function is defined from the initial condition...  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=0$ or $y=2$ are where problems occur (considering that the numerator never vanishes). But the question is asking about where this occurs in terms of $x$. Since you know the relevant $y$ values, you can plug them in and search for the closest solutions to the initial point $x=0$. This gives the equations

$$2-x-x^3=0,2-x-x^3=4$$

which you can solve (though the easiest way to do this by hand is just by guess-and-check). Then $(-1,1)$ is the largest open interval containing $0$ and not containing either $-1$ or $1$.